# In MacOS, is there a way to prevent unwanted input when the screen is locked?

Tags: keyboard, lockscreen

When I walk away from my MacBook Pro (2016, if it matters), I lock the screen, but leave the laptop open.  If my cat decides to make a bed from the computer while I am away from the desk, when I return, I often find a number of programs opened once I unlock the screen.

My only assumption is this is the Touch Bar, hotkey shortcuts, or some combination of the two.  How is this even possible?  Shouldn't the computer be completely unresponsive to non-login input?  If that's not the case, how can I make that the case?  I don't want anything but the ability to log in.

Currently running Mojave (10.14.6), but this happened on prior versions as well.

Comment: How do you lock the screen? Can you reproduce the behaviour if you lock the screen and then type away on the keyboard yourself?

Comment: I lock with the ribbon lock "button".  I haven't been able to replicate the behavior manually, but I also haven't put significant time into replicating it manually.

Comment: With ribbon you mean the Touch Bar?

Comment: Did you set your Mac to lock by going to **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > General, and then select **Require Password**, as shown: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncb5z.png

Comment: Yes, Touch Bar.